# Umbraco Member Section Missing

Tags: umbraco

I am a newbie Umbraco admin.

I have logged in and see the sections pane but there is no mention of Members there - I can see Users, Content etc but not members.

When granting permissions to users, I am also missing the Members checkbox to grant access to Members.

Any ideas how to access it?

Answer (score 2):

If your user account doesn't have access to the members section you can't grant access to anyone else.

If you don't have access to the members section, chances are that whoever set up your admin account didn't check a box to allow you access to it.  Not every site uses the members section anyway.  Users get logins to do the content editing, but members are usually outsiders who are registering for newsletters and such-like.

Does your website have members?  If not then its probably fine.  Run a query against the umbraco database of:

```
select * from dbo.cmsMember
```

If it doesn't return anything then there are no members.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for coming back to me. I queried the db and there are no Members in the CMSMember table.

There is a section called Staff in the Umbraco admin panel and that seems to be laid out like you'd expect Members to be.

I'm trying to work out why some people can edit properties on their profiles and others can't. There must be some kind of permission grouping and I haven't spotted it yet.